# Execution failed for task ':app:testDebugUnitTest'. > No tests found for given includes: [com.*](filter.includeTestsMatching)

Tags: kotlin, gradle, junit5, mockk

I'm trying to migrate a project from JUnit 4 to 5. The project has had a lot of migrations lately, including the swap from Groovy DSL to Kotlin DSL, Mockito to Mockk and from 'legacy' xml to JetPack Compose.

However, when I try to migrate to JUnit 5, I keep getting the error which was mentioned in the title. I feel like I have tried everything there is, but for some reason project setups which should be working, do not seem to actually be working.
**build.gradle (project)**

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1")
        classpath("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.40.5")
    }
}

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "7.2.1" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "7.2.1" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.6.10" apply false
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.40"
}

tasks {
    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}
```

**build.gradle (module)**

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.6.10-1.0.2"
}

kotlin {
    sourceSets {
        debug {
            kotlin.srcDir("build/generated/ksp/debug/kotlin")
        }
        release {
            kotlin.srcDir("build/generated/ksp/release/kotlin")
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk = 32

    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding = true
        dataBinding = true
        compose = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 32
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.1.1"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1")

    // Compose dependencies
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:1.1.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.animation:animation:1.1.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.1.1")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.4.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.1.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.1.1")

    // Compose Nav Destinations
    implementation("io.github.raamcosta.compose-destinations:core:1.1.2-beta")
    ksp("io.github.raamcosta.compose-destinations:ksp:1.1.2-beta")

    // Used to load images from urls within compose
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.0.0-rc01")

    // View binding
    implementation("com.github.yogacp:android-viewbinding:1.0.4")

    // Dependency Injection (hilt)
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.41")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.41")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0")

    // Used to convert objects to json and reverse
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0")

    // Used for the api call
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")

    // Glide, used for loading images with urls
    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0")
    kapt("com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0")

    // Used for the coroutines
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.2")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")

    // Used for the testing
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2")
    testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.12.4")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2")
}
```

Simple test

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class TempTest {
    @Test
    fun test() {
        assert(true)
    }
}
```